# Why does indexing not refresh after applying changes to a VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba

The aim of my current code is to add a comment column to my excel sheet and then use autofilter to filter the required item ids and types for my data. When I add the comment column, I was hoping that the indexing of columns in my sheet should change, however, it doesn't any idea why this is happening?

```
Option Explicit
Sub ValidateEdgeCases()
    ' Enter Column called Comments
    Range("A:A").Insert
    Range("A1").Value = "Comment"
    Range("A1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    'Filter by ItemID blanks and types blanks and 0
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=0", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
End Sub
```

As commented the aim of the code is to add a column and filter for missing item ids and missing or 0 types.
The above code works, but when I change the fields to 2 and 3(as they should be after adding a comment column, the filter is applied to wrong columns (those to the right hand side).

Here's a small reproducible example:

| Item ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| A321_150 | 0 |
|  |  |
|  | 0 |
| A3112_123 | 2 |
| A321_150 | 3 |

Comment: I still can't figure out why the indexing within a macro doesn't change, so if you down vote, please leave a comment about what I can improve or why it might be the case

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to filter on column **B** - after you have inserted the new column A "comment":

```vb
    'Filter by ItemID blanks and types blanks and 0
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=0", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
```

Try to avoid implicit range-references (Range("A:A")) - instead always use explicit references (worksheet.range(...)).

And I would avoid to reference the activesheet. Use a variable instead that is set to the sheet (like `dim wsEdgeCases as worksheet: set wsEdgeCases = activeworkbook.worksheets("EdgeCases")`)

In case you are changing the code later you are safe if the activesheet changes.

By the way: I assume your question got down-voted as it is not quite clear what you are asking for - what do you mean by indexing?

Comment: When I use Autofilter after adding the comment column, the field argument for autofilter (which is the column number doesn't change?), however, I was hoping this would change, as there is one additional column in the worksheet now. By indexing I meant the index number of the column I am trying to filter

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand - the index of column A is 1, the index of column B is 2. When you insert a column before column A (like your new comment column) your old column A becoms column B/Index 2.  Did you try to filter on "B" - what's the result?

Comment: Yes, after adding the comment column, when I filter on column "B" it should filter the "itemID" column, but in my case it filters the "type" column.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot from the sheet after the macor run?